# Jquery each function not working as expected

Tags: jquery

Not sure I can explain this properly....

I have the following sequence of code repeated over and over:

```
<div class="featured">
    <div class="link1">
        <a href="url1">anchor1</a>
    </div>

    <div class="link2">
        <a href="url2">anchor2</a>
    </div>
</div>

...... this sequence is repeated again and again, but "url2" has different values
```

I am trying to replace "ancor1" with "url2" (for each repeated sequence, url2 has a different value).

I have used this jquery code:

```
$(".featured").each(function(){
   var url2 = $(.featured .link2 a).attr('href');
   $("link1").html(url2);
});
```

The code kinda works but it gets the "url2" value from the first sequence of code and repeats it on every itteretion.

Any ideas?

Comment: Couple of issues: Your `$("featured")` needs to be `$(".featured")` as  you are searching for a class, and not a tag. Secondly, wrap `.featured .link a` within quotes.

Comment: Not clear as to what you are wanting to achieve. Would you be able to add 'before' and 'after' HTML, i.e. what you start with, and what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
$(".featured").each(function(){
   var url2 = $(".link2 a", this).attr('href');
   $(".link1", this).html(url2);
});
```

This will specify that `.link2` and `.link1` needs to be from the current `featured` div. The second parameter to jQuery specifies the context to search within.

Comment: It works, I had a feeling I had to use "this" - but I am new to jquery and I had a deadline on this project. That's it, I'm starting tutorials. Ty!